How to add a way to navigate to a main page
I have a dashboard and my goal is to add a way for users to interact with a chatbot from the dashboard to ask questions about their data. There are two ways to launch chatbot, one that keeps you on the dashboard page with a modal overlayed on it and another that navigates you to the main page of the chatbot. The modal is a more limited experience where you can just ask questions and get answers, but you're able to stay on the dashboard. The separate, main page has the full experience where you can see past questions and activity, etc. I want to add a way for users to go from the modal to the main page if they want the full experience but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. I figure it should be some type of button but I'm not sure where to put it and what the best language would be to communicate they're going to the main page.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but Bank of America did the similar thing. The chatbot will tell the user that the information they want is on the xxx page, and there will be a button for users to select if they want to be navigated there. 
